# PHP error 500 con el servidor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo esta conexión:

conexion.php

```
<?php
   # Conexion con la Base de Datos
   $userdb = 'administrador';
   $passworddb = '123456789';
   $dbhost= 'dbserver';
   $dbname =   'sk_modular_divisiones';
   
?>
```

Tengo esta consulta para llenar un `select`:

altura.php

```
<?php
/*Escoger Altura*/
require("conexion.php");
$link= mysqli_connect($dbhost,$userdb,$passworddb,$dbname);

  or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('sk_modular_divisiones') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
  $query= "SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-148' UNION SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-160'";
  $result = mysql_query($query)
            or die("Ocurrio un error en la consulta SQL");
            mysql_close();
  echo '<option value="0">Escoger altura</option>';
  while (($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result)) != NULL) {
    echo '<option value="'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'">'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'</option>';
  }
  //liberar resultador
  mysql_free_result($result);

  //Cerrar la conexión
  mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Y tengo esta llamada *ajax*:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "php/altura.php",
       success: function(response)
       {
         $('.selector-elevation select').html(response).fadeIn();
       }
     });
    });
```

Cuando estoy en local me funciona, pero cuando lo subí al servidor me sale el siguiente error.

```
POST http://webserver/altura/php/altura.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

No se si me estoy conectando mal a la base de datos o el problema es de *ajax*.

Comment: Puede ser un problema con la ruta del archivo. Prueba la dirección en tu navegador: `http://webserver/altura/php/altura.php` si te da error 500 ya sabes donde está problema. Saludos.

Comment: y si no lo logras encontrar; los errores 500 normalmente en un web server generan un log de error; verifica en donde esta este log y fíjate que dice o pega las ultimas 20 líneas aquí para orientarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error HTTP 500 Internal server error (Error interno del servidor)
Puede ocurrir por:

1* Errores del software del servidor

2* Errores de programacion:

revisa bien tu codigo PHP, ese `OR DIE` no deberia ir asi.

```
<?php
/*Escoger Altura*/
require("conexion.php");
$link= mysqli_connect($dbhost,$userdb,$passworddb,$dbname);

/*ESTO ESTA MAL >>> syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR)*/


  or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('sk_modular_divisiones') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
  $query= "SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-148' UNION SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-160'";
  $result = mysql_query($query)
            or die("Ocurrio un error en la consulta SQL");
            mysql_close();
  echo '<option value="0">Escoger altura</option>';
  while (($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result)) != NULL) {
    echo '<option value="'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'">'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'</option>';
  }
  //liberar resultador
  mysql_free_result($result);

  //Cerrar la conexión
  mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Prueba agregando un `IF`:

```
  if ($link->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
```

**En vez del OR DIE**

```
<?php
/*Escoger Altura*/
require("conexion.php");
$link= mysqli_connect($dbhost,$userdb,$passworddb,$dbname);


  if ($link->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
    } 

   mysql_select_db('sk_modular_divisiones') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
  $query= "SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-148' UNION SELECT DISTINCT sk_tipo FROM `sk_standar` WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-160'";
  $result = mysql_query($query)
            or die("Ocurrio un error en la consulta SQL");
            mysql_close();
  echo '<option value="0">Escoger altura</option>';
  while (($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result)) != NULL) {
    echo '<option value="'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'">'.$fila["sk_tipo"].'</option>';
  }
  //liberar resultador
  mysql_free_result($result);

  //Cerrar la conexión
  mysql_close($link);
?>
```

3* Errores de rutas en los scripts

4* Errores en la configuracion del .htaccess

Veamos ahora:

Como el error solo muestra 500 puedes usar este comando para ver los errores mas especifico:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
?>
```

ahora bien, seguro que esto "*php/altura.php*" esta dentro de tu servidor?

Has borrado el cache para que actualice los codigos y los archivos? `control+shift+R`

Comment: Me dice lo siguiente `No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión. (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in D:\Modular\php\DB.php on line 13`. No se por que me dice localhost si yo ya le di la ruta del servidor

Comment: Podrias publicar el DB.php

Answer (score 0):

Si estás desplegando en mismo servidor (app y db), prueba esto:
$dbhost= 'localhost';